# remove double entry from datatable using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

When doing a query i put the output in a datatable.

This datatable is the attached to a datagridview. In the first row i have a date field, the second row is my leave information for that date.

As you can see in the example in certain cases i get the same date twice, once with Leavetype data and once without any leavetype data.

How could i run trough every entry in the datatable en remove the line if the same date is present more then once in the list, and in that case remove the line where Leavetype is empty?

```
Date        |  Leavetype
------------|-----------
01-01-2016  |  leave
02-01-2016  |  work
02-01-2016  |
```

The query i used is :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Date, b.Leavetype FROM Kalender a LEFT JOIN VerlofLijn ON a.ID = c.DagID LEFT JOIN Verloftype b ON c.VerloftypeID = b.ID AND c.Persnummer=@pnummer WHERE a.Date >= " + startdate+ " and a.Datum <" + enddate+";
```

The Dates come from another piece of code, so no user input is given.

Comment: Query duplicates (`SELECT Id, ..., COUNT(*) FROM ... HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` thing) and use it in `DELETE FROM ... WHERE Id IN (SELECT bla bla bla)`. If supported you may want to check performance with a table expression (if you care): `WITH ... DELETE ...`. _Using C#_ thing I hope it's trivial (you may also do LINQ, if you wish, with `GroupBy(x => x.Date).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` but I'm not sure about its performance

Comment: yes but i can't remove them from database. They should be removed from the datatable in the code, after the query.

Comment: Then show us you query!!!

Comment: Please edit your question, don't post code in comments. Hint: you're using **LEFT** JOIN. Slightly off-topic but mandatory warning: don't build SQL commands with concatenation (especially but not only if input comes from users).

Comment: Why is **LEFT JOIN** not correct?

Comment: It's not incorrect but it will also return rows with NULL Leavetype, try to add HAVING from first comment

Comment: I need it to return rows with null leavtype as well, since its a calendar. But for some reason it adds the same date more then once when others have entered a leavetype on the same date